# Multivariate normal - conditioning on absolute values

Tags: multivariate-analysis, finance, moments, conditional-expectation

I’m reading a paper and really struggling with one appendix. Basically they derive conditional expectation of a multivariate normal, conditioning on absolute values.

Let
$$\boldsymbol y
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 \boldsymbol y_{a}^{\top} \\
 \boldsymbol y_{b}^{\top}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$\boldsymbol y  \sim \mathcal{N}({\boldsymbol 0},{\Sigma_{y}})$$

where
 $$ \Sigma_{y} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{aa}  & \Sigma_{ab}\\
\Sigma_{ba}  &  \Sigma_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}$$

it is known that $E[y_a|y_b]=\Sigma_{ab}\Sigma_{bb}^{-1} \boldsymbol y_b $

The bit I'm struggling with is:

Let

$\boldsymbol y_a=y_1$ and $\boldsymbol y_b^\top=(y_2,y_3) .$ We want to calculate the conditional expectation: $ E[y_1|y_2 = l_2, |y_3|=l_3]. $ 
Define $f(\boldsymbol y_b) = e^{-1/2 \boldsymbol{ y_{b}^{\top}\Sigma_{bb}^{-1}y_{b}}} $ and let $\boldsymbol l_b = (l_2,l_3)$

according to the paper it is easy to show that:

$ E[y_1|y_2 = l_2, |y_3|=l_3] = \boldsymbol{\Sigma_{ab} \Sigma_{bb}^{-1} \{  i_{11}^{(2,2)}-\tanh[l_{b}^{\top} i_{11}^{(2,2)} \Sigma_{bb}^{-1}i_{22}^{(2,2)} l_{b}]i_{22}^{(2,2)}l_{b}\}}  $

where $i_{ij}^{(m,n)}$ is the index matrix.

Then they continue with a even more complicated conditional expectation which I would also like to understand. The link the paper:
http://web.mit.edu/wangj/Public/Publication/Wang94.pdf
page 163.

I would be extremely grateful if somebody would be able to help me with this.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a simple problem made hard by truly awful notation (which, frankly, I don't even want to try to decipher).  The absolute value is not an issue due to the symmetry of the distribution around zero. Consider computing two conditional expectations: one for $y_3=l_3$ and another for $y_3=-l_3$, and then combining them.